# `systemctl show` outputs incorrect MemoryCurrent value

Tags: centos7, systemd, memory-usage, systemctl, cgroup

on one box, `systemctl show` get an incorrect value for unit memory usage:

```
$ systemctl show crond | grep MemoryCurrent
MemoryCurrent=18446744073709551615
```

`18446744073709551615 == UINT64_MAX`, this must be incorrect.

but another box shows correct memory usage:

```
$ systemctl show crond | grep MemoryCurrent
MemoryCurrent=1490944
```

both machines use `CentOS7` and preshipped `systemd 219`:

```
# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

and have set `MemoryAccounting=no`.

how to make systemctl/systemd behavior correctly?

see also in the [related mailing list thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-July/041092.html) and [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901075/systemctl-status-not-showing-cpu-memory-usage).